# Boost Fusion compile error in VS 2013 RC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, visual-studio-2013, boost-fusion

Hello I got the latest Boost from trunk which builds with VS 2013 RC.  Built boost, it worked.

But when compiling my project against Boost, where I make use of Boost Fusion.  I'm getting 100's of these error messages--

Error   1086    error C3520: 'T' : parameter pack must be expanded in this context

It refers to this code in make_vector10.hpp

```
namespace result_of
{
    template <typename T0 , typename T1 , typename T2>
    struct make_vector<T0 , T1 , T2>
    {
        typedef vector3<typename detail::as_fusion_element<T0>::type , typename detail::as_fusion_element<T1>::type , typename detail::as_fusion_element<T2>::type> type;
    };
}
```

But there is no template parameter "T" used anywhere here.

This is also not a variadic template so I don't understand why it refers to parameter packs in the error message.  "vector3" and "as_fusion_element" are also not variadic.

All variations of make_vector are giving me the same error btw(also make_set).

Anyone know what is going on here? Thanks

Here is a minimal repro

```
#include <boost/fusion/container.hpp> 
#include <boost/fusion/algorithm.hpp> 
#include <boost/fusion/include/algorithm.hpp>           
#include <boost/fusion/sequence.hpp> 
#include <boost/fusion/include/sequence.hpp> 
#include <boost/fusion/support/pair.hpp> 
#include <boost/fusion/include/pair.hpp>

namespace fs = boost::fusion;

namespace Key {

 struct prep_table{}; struct draw_single{};

};

int main() {

fs::map<std::pair<Key::prep_table, float>, std::pair<Key::draw_single, int>> Blah;

return 0;

}
```

Comment: I doubt that this will help, but can you try using `#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_TR1` before the inclusion of any fusion headers. You can also try `#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE` but I guess that this is the default one. (I don't have access to visual studio so unfortunately I can't check that this works).

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but no luck.  I reverted fusion to an older version that wasn't making use of any variadic templates so that I could get my project compiling.  The error message VS is spitting out is useless and just doesn't contain enough information to pinpoint where the real problem is.

Comment: I stepped over the same problem in I got a confirmation by MS that this is a bug: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/811306/compile-error-with-boost-fusion and will be fixed in the next update

Comment: Thanks for the link to the MSVC bug!  I am experiencing this problem with Visual Studio Pro 2013 Update 1.  The bug report does not indicate when a fix would be available.  Does anyone have more info?

Answer (score 1):

It was a [compiler bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/811306/compile-error-with-boost-fusion) as reported by Felix Petroconi in the comments.

Work around: get latest boost, but roll back fusion to an earlier version